# Objectbox not saving list of objects

Tags: android, kotlin, objectbox

I'm attempting to save a custom object (called Data) that contains a list of (Datafield) objects. When i use the objectbox browser admin i am unable to see the column for the data at all and only see the UID listed under relations but not in the Data object definition of the json
Here is the code i have for a Data object

```
@Entity
data class Data(
    @Id
    var id: Long = 0,
    var name: String = "",
    var lastEdited: String = "",
    var dataFields: List<DataField> = listOf(),
)
```

and here is the code i have for a Datafield object

```
@Entity
data class DataField(
    @Id
    var id: Long,
    @Unique(onConflict = ConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    var fieldName: String = "",
    var dataFieldType: Int = DataFieldType.SHORTSTRING.ordinal,
    var dataValue: String = "",
    var first: String = "",
    var second: String = "",
    var third: String = "",
    var isEnabled: Boolean = true,
    var fieldHint: String? = "Enter value for $fieldName"
)
```

one Data object should contain a list of Data field objects.  I've rebuilt my objectbox model and deleted the in app data/cache on the virtual device all to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, there are two options:

- make the dataFields property a relation (ToMany in this case, https://docs.objectbox.io/relations) or
- provide a getter and setter that converts to/from a supported type (https://docs.objectbox.io/advanced/custom-types#convert-annotation-and-property-converter), e.g. a string in JSON format.

Comment: Yeah, I added a property called dataId and then used it to link dataItems to data objects.

Answer (score 0):

According to best of my experience.

there is no batch insert, you have to use loop, and extract each element and save it....

Comment: Pretty sure object box can insert a list of objects. This is even slightly different because the list is actually prepopulated for the data item and then the single data item is added. Im thinking to make a class of type data item that will hold a data_id that will be the rows and linked by that foreign key